# Get html Ast in Final release

Tags: angular

## Context

I'm creating an extractor for some html elements in my application, some elements like `<foo key="FOO_KEY">My Value</foo>` need to be extracted to be all in a json for i18n purpose.

Because of some specific needs, I can't use angular2 i18n system, so I created my own, using a `component`, a `pipe` and a `service`.

To extract service calls, I can wrap `typescript` compiler and that's what I've done.
Since the last version of my tool (made using angular2 `v2.0.0-rc.1`) I was perfectly able to get an HTML Ast using those imports:

```
import {HtmlParser} from "@angular/compiler/src/html_parser";
import {HtmlElementAst, HtmlAttrAst} from "@angular/compiler/src/html_ast";
```

and parsing the html templates, then getting what I need using the Ast.

## Problem

I updated to angular2 `v2.0.X` and my imports below are not exported anymore. So I'm not able to extract HTML Ast anymore, which is a big issue since it's the only proper way to extract data from html (regex is not an option, see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags))

Answer (score 1):

In v2.0.0-rc.5 was made breaking changes. Today it looks like:

```
import { HtmlParser } from "@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/html_parser";
import { Element, Attribute } from '@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/ast';
```

Comment: I removed the answer check because it's not solving my problem finally :/. since angular2 final is es2015 and my app is a ndoe app, it can't understand es2015, so the importe are not the good ones